# Modify Nice-Matrix Table

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I want to shade the headers and sidebars of this `nice matrix` table. I also want to change the position of the sidebars to the right.

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
%\title{\vspace{-1cm}}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
%if you put <showframe> option in \usepackage[]{geometry} it will produce frame round the document
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % to boldface fifure and table caption
\usepackage{Times}% for font thst is close to times new roman 
\usepackage{inputenc,float,caption,subcaption,enumitem}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,font=normalfont,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,font=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\newcommand{\boldm}[1] {\mathversion{bold}#1\mathversion{normal}} % to validate \boldm function
\usepackage{xfrac} % to validate \sfrac{num}{denom}

\begin{document}%\layout

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \caption{My Caption}
        \label{tabb1}
        % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
        % \usepackage{multirow}
        % \usepackage{graphicx}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 1}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 1.58 & 2.89 & 3.50 & 4.85 & 5.89 & 6.20 & 7.45 & 8.39 & 9.26 & 10.88 & 11.29 & 12.01\\
                & MBBR & 1.58 & 2.80 & 3.43 & 4.85 & 5.83 & 6.01 & 7.40 & 8.34 & 9.12 & 10.17 & 11.21 & 12.87\\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 3}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 1.75 & 2.67 & 3.65 & 4.55 & 5.67 & 6.60 & 7.72 & 8.18 & 9.79 & 10.21 & 11.01 & 12.03 \\
                & MBBR & 1.73 & 2.41 & 3.29 & 4.55 & 5.50 & 6.04 & 7.19 & 8.02 & 9.37 & 10.63 & 11.64 & 12.60 \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 5}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 1.92 & 2.45 & 3.76 & 4.26 & 5.45 & 6.01 & 7.87 & 8.97 & 9.32 & 10.34 & 11.69 & 12.05 \\
                & MBBR & 1.89 & 2.02 & 3.15 & 4.26 & 5.17 & 6.07 & 7.98 & 8.70 & 9.62 & 10.39 & 11.07 & 12.34 \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 10}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 15.83 & 8.90 & 15.52 & 18.52 & 8.90 & 12.01 & 15.74 & 13.93 & 12.65 & 10.68 & 13.38 & 10.11\\
                & MBBR & 15.77 & 8.04 & 14.30 & 18.51 & 8.34 & 10.13 & 13.96 & 13.41 & 11.23 & 8.78 & 12.14 & 8.68\\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want [image: something like this]

**EDITED**

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
%\title{\vspace{-1cm}}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
%if you put <showframe> option in \usepackage[]{geometry} it will produce frame round the document
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % to boldface fifure and table caption
\usepackage{Times}% for font thst is close to times new roman 
\usepackage{inputenc,float,caption,subcaption,enumitem}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,font=normalfont,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,font=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\newcommand{\boldm}[1] {\mathversion{bold}#1\mathversion{normal}} % to validate \boldm function
\usepackage{xfrac} % to validate \sfrac{num}{denom}

\begin{document}%\layout

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \caption{My Caption}
        \label{tabb1}
        % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
        % \usepackage{multirow}
        % \usepackage{graphicx}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 1}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 1.58 & 2.89 & 3.50 & 4.85 & 5.89 & 6.20 & 7.45 & 8.39 & 9.26 & 10.88 & 11.29 & 12.01\\
                & MBBR & 1.58 & 2.80 & 3.43 & 4.85 & 5.83 & 6.01 & 7.40 & 8.34 & 9.12 & 10.17 & 11.21 & 12.87\\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 3}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 1.75 & 2.67 & 3.65 & 4.55 & 5.67 & 6.60 & 7.72 & 8.18 & 9.79 & 10.21 & 11.01 & 12.03 \\
                & MBBR & 1.73 & 2.41 & 3.29 & 4.55 & 5.50 & 6.04 & 7.19 & 8.02 & 9.37 & 10.63 & 11.64 & 12.60 \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 5}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 1.92 & 2.45 & 3.76 & 4.26 & 5.45 & 6.01 & 7.87 & 8.97 & 9.32 & 10.34 & 11.69 & 12.05 \\
                & MBBR & 1.89 & 2.02 & 3.15 & 4.26 & 5.17 & 6.07 & 7.98 & 8.70 & 9.62 & 10.39 & 11.07 & 12.34 \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 10}$}
                & \Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} \\ 
                & & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} \\ 
                & MBB  & 15.83 & 8.90 & 15.52 & 18.52 & 8.90 & 12.01 & 15.74 & 13.93 & 12.65 & 10.68 & 13.38 & 10.11\\
                & MBBR & 15.77 & 8.04 & 14.30 & 18.51 & 8.34 & 10.13 & 13.96 & 13.41 & 11.23 & 8.78 & 12.14 & 8.68\\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

I now want [image: something like this]

Comment: Just add `[fill=gray!50]` (or whatever color you want) after `\Block`.

Comment: Please, make your document example minimal (MWE) and compilable, It contain errors ...

Comment: I have adjusted the code in response to your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

In your document example you load `caption` and `subcaption` twice, even worse with different options. Remove duplicate!

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
%\title{\vspace{-1cm}}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
%if you put <showframe> option in \usepackage[]{geometry} it will produce frame round the document
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % to boldface fifure and table caption
\usepackage{Times}% for font thst is close to times new roman
\usepackage{inputenc,float,enumitem}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,font=normalfont,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,font=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\newcommand{\boldm}[1] {\mathversion{bold}#1\mathversion{normal}} % to validate \boldm function
\usepackage{xfrac} % to validate \sfrac{num}{denom}

\begin{document}%\layout

    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \caption{My Caption}
        \label{tabb1}
        % Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
        % \usepackage{multirow}
        % \usepackage{graphicx}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}               
\Block{2-1}{}
    & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$}
        &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$}
            &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$}
                &&&&   \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 1}$}                     \\
    & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$}
        & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
            & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} &   \\
MBB  & 1.58 & 2.89 & 3.50 & 4.85 & 5.89 & 6.20 & 7.45 & 8.39 & 9.26 & 10.88 & 11.29 & 12.01 &   \\
MBBR & 1.58 & 2.80 & 3.43 & 4.85 & 5.83 & 6.01 & 7.40 & 8.34 & 9.12 & 10.17 & 11.21 & 12.87 &   \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} 
    &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} 
        &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$}
            &&&&    \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 3}$}    \\
    & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
        & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
            & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$}     &   \\
MBB  & 1.75 & 2.67 & 3.65 & 4.55 & 5.67 & 6.60 & 7.72 & 8.18 & 9.79 & 10.21 & 11.01 & 12.03     &   \\
MBBR & 1.73 & 2.41 & 3.29 & 4.55 & 5.50 & 6.04 & 7.19 & 8.02 & 9.37 & 10.63 & 11.64 & 12.60     &   \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} 
    &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} 
        &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} 
            &&&&     \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 5}$}                           \\
    & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
        & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
            & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$}     &   \\
MBB  & 1.92 & 2.45 & 3.76 & 4.26 & 5.45 & 6.01 & 7.87 & 8.97 & 9.32 & 10.34 & 11.69 & 12.05     &   \\
MBBR & 1.89 & 2.02 & 3.15 & 4.26 & 5.17 & 6.07 & 7.98 & 8.70 & 9.62 & 10.39 & 11.07 & 12.34     &   \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{5.4em}{%%
            \begin{NiceTabular}{l>{\bfseries}lcccccccccccc}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{} & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$} 
    &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$} 
        &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$} 
            &&&&    \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 10}$}       \\
    & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
        & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$} 
            & {\boldm $n = 10$} & {\boldm $n = 15$} & {\boldm $n = 20$} & {\boldm $n = 25$}         &   \\
MBB  & 15.83 & 8.90 & 15.52 & 18.52 & 8.90 & 12.01 & 15.74 & 13.93 & 12.65 & 10.68 & 13.38 & 10.11  &   \\
MBBR & 15.77 & 8.04 & 14.30 & 18.51 & 8.34 & 10.13 & 13.96 & 13.41 & 11.23 & 8.78 & 12.14 & 8.68    &   \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
        }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

BTW, to my opinion, most rows are redundant. They just repeat column headers in the first table. Also using `\resizebox` deformate table. Font are not consistent anymore and to my opinion very ugly. I would redesign table so, that resize box will not be needed anymore. Fore example the first table (in other three tables I would remove the first two rows):

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=15mm,top=15mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % to boldface figure and table caption
\usepackage{Times}% for font thst is close to times new roman
\usepackage{inputenc,float,enumitem}
\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf,font=normalfont,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,font=bf,labelsep=colon]{subcaption}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}

\newcommand{\boldm}[1] {\mathversion{bold}#1\mathversion{normal}} % to validate \boldm function
\usepackage{xfrac} % to validate \sfrac{num}{denom}

\begin{document}%\layout

    \begin{table}[H]
\centering
\small
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tabb1}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{r>{\bfseries}l *{12}{c}}[hvlines]
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}               
\Block{2-1}{}
    & \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.8$}
        &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.9$}
            &&&& \Block[fill=gray!30]{1-4}{\boldm $\varphi = 0.95$}
                &&&&   \Block[fill=gray!30]{*-1}{\rotate $\mathbf{sd = 1}$}                     \\
$n$ & 10    & 15    & 20    &   25  
        & 10    & 15    & 20    &   25 
            & 10    & 15    & 20    &   25      &       \\
MBB  & 1.58 & 2.89 & 3.50 & 4.85 & 5.89 & 6.20 & 7.45 & 8.39 & 9.26 & 10.88 & 11.29 & 12.01 &   \\
MBBR & 1.58 & 2.80 & 3.43 & 4.85 & 5.83 & 6.01 & 7.40 & 8.34 & 9.12 & 10.17 & 11.21 & 12.87 &   \\
            \end{NiceTabular}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addedndum:**
For comparison redesign of this table where is used zhr `tabularray` package:

- *pros*: for final result is needed only one compilation
- *cons*: due to new design a bit more complex table preamble and compilation take some time

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage[hmargin={2cm,15mm},vmargin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{Times, bm}% for font thst is close to times new roman
\usepackage[font=large,
            labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{$sd=10$}
\caption{My Caption}
\label{tab:b1}
    \begin{tblr}{hline{1} = {2-Y}{1pt},           hline{2} = {1-Y}{solid},   
                 hline{even [3-Z]} = {solid, gray}, hline{odd [3-Z]} = {1pt},  
                 vline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},           vline{Z} = {3-Z}{solid}, vline{2-Y}={solid},
                 colsep=4pt,
                 colspec={r X[c, font=\bfseries] *{11}{X[c]} c},
                 cell{1}{2-Y}={bg=gray!30},
                 cell{3-Z}{Z}={bg=gray!30, cmd=\rotcell[cc]},  
                 vspan=even               
                }
    &   \SetCell[c=4]{c,$}    \bm{\varphi = 0.8}
        &&&&    \SetCell[c=4]{c,$}    \bm{\varphi = 0.9}
                &&&&    \SetCell[c=4]{c,$}    \bm{\varphi = 0.95}
                        &&&&        \\
$n$ & 10    & 15    & 20    &   25
        & 10    & 15    & 20    &   25
            & 10    & 15    & 20    &   25  &                                                \\
MBB  & 1.58 & 2.89 & 3.50 & 4.85 
        & 5.89 & 6.20 & 7.45 & 8.39 
            & 9.26 & 10.88 & 11.29 & 12.01 
                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}       $\bm{sd=1}$    \\
MBBR & 1.58 & 2.80 & 3.43 & 4.85 & 5.83 & 6.01 & 7.40 & 8.34 & 9.12 & 10.17 & 11.21 & 12.87 &   \\
%
MBB  & 1.75 & 2.67 & 3.65 & 4.55 & 5.67 & 6.60 & 7.72 & 8.18 & 9.79 & 10.21 & 11.01 & 12.03  
                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}       $\bm{sd=3}$    \\
MBBR & 1.73 & 2.41 & 3.29 & 4.55 & 5.50 & 6.04 & 7.19 & 8.02 & 9.37 & 10.63 & 11.64 & 12.60     &   \\
%
MBB  & 1.92 & 2.45 & 3.76 & 4.26 & 5.45 & 6.01 & 7.87 & 8.97 & 9.32 & 10.34 & 11.69 & 12.05     
                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}       $\bm{sd=5}$    \\
MBBR & 1.89 & 2.02 & 3.15 & 4.26 & 5.17 & 6.07 & 7.98 & 8.70 & 9.62 & 10.39 & 11.07 & 12.34     &   \\
%
MBB  & 15.83 & 8.90 & 15.52 & 18.52 & 8.90 & 12.01 & 15.74 & 13.93 & 12.65 & 10.68 & 13.38 & 10.11  
                &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}       $\bm{sd=10}$    \\
MBBR & 15.77 & 8.04 & 14.30 & 18.51 & 8.34 & 10.13 & 13.96 & 13.41 & 11.23 & 8.78 & 12.14 & 8.68    &   \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Error message: `File tabularray.sty not found`

Comment: Are you have installed it?

Comment: I tried instaling it but it will not work

Comment: @DanielJames, "will not work" is not an information what is going wrong at your place.  I haven't any idea, how you installed package, which LaTeX distribution you use etc. Sorry ...